# How to let the input text in Streamlit only accept string not number?

Tags: python, streamlit

how can i let the st.input_text only accept string ? and if user enter numbers, an error message would pop-up. Does anyone have the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will force the input to be string:

```
user_input = st.text_input("label goes here", default_value_goes_here)
if user_input.isalpha():
        st.write(text, 'string', )
    else:
        st.write('Please type in a string ')
```

Answer (score 2):

isalpha( ) is a good choice that works. The following is an app that only allows strings as the input.

```
def main():
    st.title("Only allow text example")
    
    text = str(st.text_input('Type something'))

    #only allow strings
    if text.isalpha():
        st.write(text, '...works as its a string', )
    else:
        st.write('Please type in a string ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***.isalpha() #returns true if
the string before the . is alphabetic.

```
a = input("Enter input:")
if not a.isalpha():
    print("Oops!  That was no valid string.  Try again...")
```